# Make clang ignore empty wildcard

Tags: c++, c, clang, wildcard

I would like to make clang compile both C and C++ files in the directory (if any). To achieve this, I run clang as follows: `clang *.c *.cpp`. My issue is that it refuses to run if there's no files of one type: `clang: error: no such file or directory: '/mnt/c/test/*.c'`
Is there a way to make clang ignore wildcards that don't match any files?

Thank you

Comment: Are you using a build tool at all, like make or cmake? This isn't that hard with make, but it takes a little creativity.

Comment: I could, but I am already running clang from inside of Node.js so I'd like to avoid using other packages, if possible

Comment: Ah, then you can code something to produce a real list?

Comment: That's not `clang`, it's your shell. You can't make `clang` ignore what you feed it. Try setting `shopt -s nullglob` before you compile.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'm using `sh`, shouldn't empty wildcard just expand to nothing?

Comment: @MikhailStefantsev Not by default. Try the option I put above. `shopt -s nullglob` that is. You can set it back with `shopt -u nullglob`. I'm assuming `bash` not `sh` though. I don't think `sh` is around in many places anymore.

Comment: @TedLyngmo You can send it as an answer, if you like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the built in shell globbing in `bash`, not with `clang`. You can't make `clang` ignore what you feed it and a non-matching globbing will send the result unexpanded (since there's nothing to expand). To turn off the default globbing so that no matches results in an empty match:

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

To turn it on again

```
shopt -u nullglob
```